# SUMIF for multi-data condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, worksheet-function, sumifs

I have a sheet with a very uncommon structure like so:

```
   A        B       C
1  John     Β7      job1
2           10      xxx
3  Steven   B7      job2
4           12      yyy
5  Mark     D3      job2
6           8       zzz
7  Uli      B7      job1
8           8       vvv
```

It's like every data cell is divided into four subcells (e.g. `John` -> his data are in B1, C1, B2 and C2). Let's say the upper-left subcell (B1, B3, ...) is a `working place` ID, upper-right subcell is `job` ID and bottom-left are working hours.

Is there a way to sum the working hours (in cells B2, B4, B6 and so on) for each combination [`working place`, `job`, `name`], so the result would be?:

```
    A       B       C

31  B7      job1    18
32          job2    12
33  D3      job1    0
34          job2    8
```

Comment: Why doesn't a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) doesn't work in C31. Do you need to *Fill Down* from A31:A32?

Comment: 1) I don't think there is anything important in output column A and B - i just provided some sample labels for clarity, but the important part is output in column C - the sums.
2) I tried to do it with SUMIF, but i failed to cover all the data "spread" across different "subcells". If you provide appropriate function, I'll definitely give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to turn on Record Macro first if this is required often.

Copy ColumnsB:C to D1. Delete D1:E1 with Shift cells up. Insert a new Row1 and series fill A1:E1. Filter on ColumnA to select (blanks) only and delete the selected rows.

If you want `0` to show in the results populate ColumnsB and C with missing combinations (in your example, `D3` in B6 and `job1` in C6).

Select A1:E6 and insert a PivotTable at the desired location (A30), with `2` and `3` for ROWS and Sum of `4` for VALUES. DESIGN > Layout - Report Layout, Show in Tabular Form and remove any Subtotals.

In Pivot Table Options, Layout & Format, check *For empty cells show* and insert `0`, OK.

The third and fifth paragraphs may be skipped (and a range adjusted) if the `0` is not required.

Comment: Thanks pnuts, I'll try to play with macros when I have access to this sheet later today.

Answer (score 1):

I'd fix the uncommon data structure first (example formulas below), then perform `SUMIFS` and any other operations you want on it.

[image]